# Remove unnecessary functions from code of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I develop my site and want maximum performance with less code. How I can minify jQuery library throught remove additional functional? Not just minify this library.
Google Closure can do it? Alternatives?

Sorry for bad english!

Comment: Use [vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: My way is pure js. But sometimes necessary opensource plugins coded with jquery while I cant time for my coding.

Comment: jQuery's not set up for Closure Compiler.

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question? People often use only a very small fraction of the jQuery library, so it's legitimate to ask if dead code can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom jQuery Builder - http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

jQuery 2.0 - http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Zepto.js - http://zeptojs.com/

Honestly, this list could go on and on, but it depends on whether you need full jQuery, what exactly your code requires, if you are using any plugins which rely on that code. It's really up to you to decide what can be removed and what can't

Answer (score 1):

Removing functions in jQuery, even if you can does not give you additional performance. What you want is probably reduce the amount of bandwidth that the library will take by minifying it(well, you already know that don't you?) or loading it off a CDN. You may also want to take a look at [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/), a smaller and compact jquery compatible library.